# How to convert this date format: /Date(1268524800000)/?

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, date

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to format a JSON date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

I am calling a JSON web service via Javascript, and the `StartDate` field is `/Date(1268524800000)/`. How do I convert this to a human readable format?d

Comment: What format is it in? Is it a time stamp? If the web service has  documentation, it should be in there

Comment: Same as this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

Comment: Well, this format is arguably not immediately recognizable. I think this many downvotes are a little harsh. (But +1 @Nathan for finding a great dupe)

Comment: the web service help says the type is "type="xs:dateTime""

Comment: It appears to be milliseconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 UTC; the date represented is Sun 2010-03-14 00:00:00 UTC.  (This doesn't answer the question of how to convert it, but it provides a clue of how to do it if you're using some language other than JavaScript.)  Of course, one way to convert it to human-readable format is to train yourself to read that format.  8-)}

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this:

```
var str = "/Date(1268524800000)/";
var num = parseInt(str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, ""));
var date = new Date(num);
alert(date);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dS2hd/

Comment: What if the number is negative?

Comment: it shouldn't be because it really does represent a date from the system

Comment: @TruMan1 - Any date before 1969 has a negative serial number in JavaScript.

Comment: didn't know about that backreference before @gilly3:

`/(\-?\d+)/.test(str) ? new Date(+RegExp.$1) : null;`

Comment: The answer given here is faster, since it doesn't require regex parsing: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2316066/163227

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to get the milliseconds, then use the Date constructor to get a Date object. Once you have your date object, you can do whatever you want with it.

```
var ms = parseInt("/Date(1268524800000)/".match(/\((\d+)\)/)[1]);
var d = new Date(ms);
alert(d.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can either `eval()` it, or you can extract the number and pass it to a `Date` constructor.

```
if (/^\/Date\((-?\d+)\)\/$/.test(val)) {
    var serial = parseInt(RegExp.$1);
    val = new Date(serial);
}
```

I've seen dates expressed as `/Date(1234567890000-0500)/`, so a more robust procedure may be called for to handle the UTC offset.